# Why is my PHP website not rendering any CSS nor links?

Tags: php, html, css

I had a personal website a while back (2016-2018) running on PHP 7.1 and everything was going fine. Recently, I spun it back up again to make some changes, upgraded my local PHP web server to 7.4 and I come to find out that for some reason, none of my CSS renders on the page. They appear to be loaded via the `<head>` tag. In addition, when clicking on any of my links which ought to take me to other internal pages just gives me a 404 error. Finally, none of the images will load either. However, if I navigate to the path directly, the images and css files are all there.

Let's say I'm running my PHP server on `http://localhost:8080`. If I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/img/mylogo.png`, I can see the picture but on the website itself, I don't.

I took a look at my production site being hosted on a web hosting platform. Everything actually appears fine (CSS and images render nicely). However, the links are still broken. Why is that?

Can anyone help me out?

**header.php**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">


        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/8c321ca885.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include ('header.php'); ?>

        <title>My Homepage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">

    </head>

    <body>
            <?php include ('titleNav.php'); ?>

            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <a href="mypage1">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <a href="mypage">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <a href="mypage3">
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php include ('footer.php'); ?>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

When opening the developer tools console, I get a whole bunch of 404 Not Found errors like so:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/img/mylogo.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: in your browser, open developer tools...see if any error is showing in the console?

Comment: @reyad  Yes, I get 404 Not Found errors. Updated my original post.

Comment: pls don't mind asking this question, just making sure -> 1. does you html load properly? 2. the html you've provided(index.php), it does not include much class(other than row) or id...how did you applied css to it? and pls make sure you're running the server on proper address and port; and you're running only one server in your machine...don't run two or more servers..

Comment: replace your code with `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">`

Comment: @biesior doesn't this `/img/logo.png` an absolute path ?

Comment: @GNassro Absolute: `http://domain.tld/img/logo.png`, root-relative: `/img/logo.png`, relative: `img/logo.png`

Comment: @GNassro in most cases root-relative (optionally with `base` tag in the header) or absolute paths should be used for referencing non-external resources, especially if the webpage has nested structure or uses some kind of URL rewriting (a.k.a. [tag:routes]). However, if I understood well, in this case there was some mistake within `DocumentRoot` of the VHOST that caused that it should be fixed OR files has to be moved in the file structure to one folder up or down. BTW. Just for curiosity **noblerare** can you explain us what exactly had to be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this issue recently. In my case, I needed to move the entire project up one directory. So depending on what you're using as your local server and how your directories are set up, my guess is that's where the problem lies, not necessarily the code which looks fine.

Comment: I feel so dumb. Yes, this was it.